# Email Greeting Updater in scheduled jobs failed

Tags: email, scheduled-job

Running Drupal 7 with CiviCRM 5.6.0. Noticed in BCC'd copies of confirmation emails for an event that some records have a blank "Email Greeting" field since the template is addressing {contact.email_greeting}.

Went into Scheduled Jobs in Settings, and ran "Execute Now" on the email greeting updater and got the following error in the log:

> Settings - Scheduled Jobs Log
>   This screen presents the list of most recent 1,000 scheduled jobs log entries. > List of log entries for:
>   Greeting updater
>
> Date  Job Name    Command/Job Status/Additional Information 2018-10-10
>   15:19:49  Greeting updater     Entity: Job Action: update_greeting Summary
>   Finished execution of Greeting updater with result: Failure, Error
>   message: Mandatory key(s) missing from params array: ct, gt Details
>
> Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
>   a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}
>
> Full message:  Finished execution of Greeting updater with result:
>   Failure, Error message: Mandatory key(s) missing from params array:
>   ct, gt 2018-10-10 15:19:49    Greeting updater     Entity: Job Action:
>   update_greeting Summary Starting execution of Greeting updater Details
>
> Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
>   a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}
>
> Full message:  Starting execution of Greeting updater

Any ideas on how I an fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the required parameters for this particular job, in this case it's looking for the contact type (ct) and greeting (gt) parameters. The link below has more info on what you're choosing from.

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/#job_update_greeting

Comment: Ugh! Duh! Sorry, that totally worked!